# What is the regular expression (regex) for a certain piece of text

Tags: java, regex

I'm learning regular expressions and I'd like to know what the regular expression to grab the "path=/return/..." for the following text:

> StartTopic topic=testParser, multiCopy=false, required=true,
>   all=false, path=/Return/ReturnData/IRSW2

Any help or pointers to good sites would be much appreciated

Edit:

```
if(c.getNodeType() ==Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element cell = (Element) c;
    String value = cell.getAttribute("value");

    // So value here equals StartTopic topic=testParser, multiCopy=false, required=true, all=false, path=/Return/ReturnData/IRSW2
    if(value.contains("path")) {

        // I want just this part "path=/Return/ReturnData/IRSW2"
        // Inside regex.txt I have this text "/path=([^\,]+)/"
        String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("regex.txt"));
        String escapedChars = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(str);

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(value+escapedChars).matcher(value);
        System.out.println(matcher);

        // never enters this for loop
        if(matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(matcher);
        }
```

Output:

```
Test!
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=StartTopic topic=testParser, multiCopy=false, required=true, all=false, path=/Return/ReturnData/IRSW2/path=([^\\,]+)/ region=0,101 lastmatch=]
```

Just to be clear, I want to do something very simple.

I have a string object "value" which contains a bunch of string. I would like only a particular piece of this string which begins with "path=" and everything after it "/Return/[...etc]", I want to use this text to construct an xml file

Comment: That wil grab everything, how could it grab just the text starting from the "p" in path and including "path" itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the many ways

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String str = "StartTopic topic=testParser, multiCopy=false, required=true, all=false, path=/Return/ReturnData/IRSW2";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(".*\\s+(path=.*)$","$1"));
}
```

O/P

```
path=/Return/ReturnData/IRSW2
```

Other ways include split based on "," and grab the last element. Or just capturing the group which starts with `path..`.

Comment: Is there a more generic way of implementing this so it's not just for a certain piece of text so it can grab "path/Return/..." from any piece of text

Comment: @mosawi -  Ya . use `replaceAll(".*(path=.*?)\\s+.*","$1")`  (assuming path doesn't have spaces)

Comment: replaceAll(".*(path=.*?)\\s+.*","$1") doesn't seem to work

Comment: @mosawi - It works for me.. I tried with ` String string = "StartTopic topic=testParser, multiCopy=false, required=true, all=false, path=/Return/ReturnData/IRSW2 adsa=asda";
`

Comment: Using your method and @Kapsonfire, will report back results

Comment: I'm trying to just get "path=/Return/..." not the whole string itself, otherwise there would be no need for regex

Comment: @mosawi - yes, and this works. Removes everything from a single line except path=.... Show me your code

Comment: Added code snippet, we might be thinking of 2 different things

Answer (score 1):

/path=([^\,]+)/

assuming that the , is the seperator of name-value pairs, this code groups the value of the path parameter

( ) - defining inside is a group match
[^\,] - every char except ,
+ one or more chars

Comment: How could I represent "/path=([^\,]+)/" in Java println method? I think it needs escaping characters